# Add superscript to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add a `superscript` to the `y-axis` label in R? I tried `bquote`, but it does not do anything.

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = OUT_SNOW_F, colour = "Flux")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Orange")) +
  ylab("Snow Flux (W/m^2)") +
  labs(color = "Legend") +
  ggtitle("Title")
```

Comment: pass an expression `ylab(expression(Flux~(W/m^2)))`

Comment: Is it a superscript "2" you'd like to add?  I find it easiest to use the unicode for the character - U+00B2. Look at this post if you want to see how to use unicode in ggplot - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039262/using-unicode-character-plus-minus-sign-inside-ggplot2

Comment: @user20650, I get an error `non-numeric argument to binary operator`, which is fixed by `ylab(expression("Snow Flux"~(W/m^2)))`

Comment: @Mandalorian; well you did edit the text ;) . As an alt. you can also join different words using the tilde operator, which is a way to add whitespace e.g. `ylab(expression(Snow~Flux~(W/m^2)))`